# Change link background on div focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with lots of large images set to 100% width. The navigation takes you to each individual image. I want the background of the link that ties to the div that is in focus to change color either because it was scrolled to or the link was clicked.

**html:**

```html
<!------ Start Header Wrapper ------>
<div class="HeadWrapper">
    <!------ Start Head ------>
    <div class="Head">
        <!------ Logo Box ------>
        <div class="Logo">
            <a href="#LBHome"><img src="_images/nav/PrimalLogo.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <!------ Navigation links when in mobile all links except shop will go under a menu icon. ------>
        <div class="NavSpan">
            <a href="#LBHelix">Helix</a>
            <a href="#LBOriginals">Originals</a>
            <a href="#LBBlackLabel">Black Label</a>
            <a href="#LBMilitary">Military</a>
            <a href="#LBBandR">Beer & Rock</a>
            <a href="#LBCustom">Custom</a>
            <a href="#LBCommunity">Community</a>
        </div>


        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!------ End Head ------>

    <!------ Transparent BG ------>
    <div class="HeaderBG"></div>

</div> 
<!------ End Header Wrapper ------>   


<!------ Start Images ------>
<div id="LBHome">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/01_LB_MtEvansRDSky.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBMHelix">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/02_Lookbook.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBWHelix" class="theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlide">
        <img src="_images/bodyImages/01_LB_MtEvansRDSky.jpg" />
        <img src="_images/bodyImages/02_Lookbook.jpg" />
        <img src="_images/bodyImages/03_Helix_V2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="LBMOriginals">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/03_Helix_V2.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBWOriginals">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/04_LB_Helix.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBBlackLabel">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/05_LB_Helix.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBMilitary">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/06_WMS-Helix.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBBandR">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/01_LB_MtEvansRDSky.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBCustom">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/01_LB_MtEvansRDSky.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="LBCommunity">
    <img src="_images/bodyImages/01_LB_MtEvansRDSky.jpg" />
</div>
```

**css:**

```css
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#1e1e1e;
}
* {
    margin:0 auto!important;
    padding:0 auto!important;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    border: none;
}
a {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#B70809;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color:#b70809;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    outline-width:0;
    border-width:0;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:#7c7c7c;
}
/*------------------------------------*\
Header
\*------------------------------------*/
.HeadWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    z-index:100;
    clear:both;
    position:fixed;
    border-bottom:1px #1e1e1e solid;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.HeaderBG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#1e1e1e;
    z-index:101;
    /* These three lines are for transparency in all browsers. */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:.7;
}
.Head {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:80px;
    z-index:105;
    display:block;
}
.Logo {
    width:86px;
    float:left;
}
/*------------------------------------*\
NAV 
\*------------------------------------*/
.NavSpan {
    float:left;
}
.NavSpan a {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:80px;
    margin-left:40px !important;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
.NavSpan a:focus {
    background:#b70809;
}
.NavSpan a:active {
    background:#b70809;
}
```

I tried doing it with an `:focus` or `:active` tag. I know there is a lot that I can do with JavaScript but I was attempting to leave out any JavaScript if possible. I desire that when a user scrolls down the page the red box under the nav item moves with the section they are in. I know I can do it with a parallax scroller or by getting window position and setting actions to happen at certain positions just wasn't sure if there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: And I want lots of money.  What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: and what is your other code? `The navigation takes you to each individual image.` blah blah.... maybe a picture?

Comment: I will take 5$ less than @AleksG if you want me to do

Comment: Just noticed you been member for 3 months!!! But seem you haven't visited [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Try this function. It will change the CSS `background-color` of the div when a click is made on the image, you can change that to anything!

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('img').click(function () {
    $('div').css('background-color', '#hexcode');
  });
});
```

**Remember:** Show us your code first! Tell us what you were doing and what went wrong. We will help you. Instead these guys are going to downvote you buddy. Try to keep this in mind for the next question as this not a freelancer site. Its a Q&A site, you ask about what is wrong we tell! That's how it goes. Also, I would like to advise you to go to this site and learn some jQuery. [jquery.com](http://jquery.com). You need to polish your JavaScript talent! :)

Comment: A small change I'd recommend is to actually use addClass/removeClass instead, to make the actual color settable in the CSS rather than having it hardcoded in the javascript. The app is much more maintainable that way.

Comment: That's also better, but this guy will move onto other image and that will either reload the page, or the whole div! So that's not an issue, the issue must have been if it was an Ajax request to populate the div! Then the div would have been same, and a need for class would be needed! However your idea is also perfect I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you Afzaal...the end goal is for a look book for a company...the user will either be clicking the items on the nav or scrolling through the page. either way we were looking to highlight the section of the look book they were in. I know in a parallax scroll it is possible and that may be the best way to do it. just wasnt sure if there were other ways to do it.